# Keep Getting Assigned Failed Projects

Tags: career-development, projects

I am with my current firm 6 years (have been in software for 30 total). The last four projects I have received (over a two year period) have shared a consistent pattern:  they were originally someone else's and were going down the drain and I get transferred to "take over".  The first two with lots of unpaid OT we were able to get out of the mud, got no recognition.  The third one couldn't be completely rescued, bad decision at the start before I arrived on an underlying commercial product that just couldn't due the job.  Again after long hours we were able to make it workable, but the project was a failure and though I only joined when the project was 3/4 completed the mud got on me and stuck in a "did not meet expectations review" (the original manager who made the bad decision bided some time in a feasibility study and then got promoted).

Today, I got called into the boss and was told that the Lead on a project was fired for "not doing a good job" and that the project is now mine. From people I know and respect I know that in senior meetings this project as a bullseye on it. I was honest in saying I was concerned with the health of the project and was told "its actually in good shape" (if you believed that then why did you fire the lead?)

Just to be clear, each project move also occured around a company reorg, so managers are different.  I have some feelings as to what is going on here, but would appreciate some independent takes as to this pattern and how to break it.  One time I would like to start with a clean sheet and manager my own mistakes.

Comment: Are you the "goto" guy in your office? Or are you saying that there is a conspiracy to give you the dead in the mud projects to work on?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0omsJooBO2Y (I Promise its not [Rick Astley](http://www.vevo.com/watch/rick-astley/never-gonna-give-you-up/GB1108700010) )

Comment: @chad I don't get it. Are you suggesting that there is a conspiracy?

Comment: I'm confused. What question are you asking of the community?

Comment: @NotVonKaiser I believe the OP is stressed out and venting a bit. But I believe a good question would be: "How should I react to being placed in impossible situation?" or "Should I asked for more compensation?"

Comment: @NotVonKaiser can we edit the question and ask a question on behalf of the asker?

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of reasons people get put on failing projects. By the looks of your results I put you in the first category.

You're seen as someone who can get things done when it all goes South, so you're a valuable asset in that sense. The bit that worries me about your situation is that it's not being recognised at reviews. Instead you're taking flak over it. This is what you need to deliberate on. Often people in this category are not promoted, they're too valuable where they are, but they should be getting regular raises. The good thing is you're getting invaluable experience under pressure.

The other category is scapegoat, a failing project is sometimes handed off to someone else because those doing it know it will all fall to bits and want to get off a sinking ship before it affects their reputations. If you feel this is what is happening then you need to mitigate against it. Life and the workplace are often unfair and people will clamber straight over others to get ahead or avoid falling back without worrying about the people they're walking on.

My way of handling it was to do pretty much the same as you, put in the hours and the sweat and make it work. But if I wasn't getting a good review after that I'd be quietly looking for a new job.

In your latest situation I would discuss this straight up with the boss.

> "The last project was failing, I fixed it with a lot of effort, and
>   yet I got a bad review. It looks like this is going down the same
>   track. Team lead has been fired for not performing. So I'll have to
>   hit the ground running, and if there's problems it will be my
>   responsibility. I don't mind the pressure, but I do mind getting a bad
>   review over things I have no control over."

And then go forwards from that conversation. If you have a problem, you need to discuss it. I've been re-reviewed and walked away with a raise in the past, just because I'll come straight out and discuss my concerns professionally.

Comment: I agree fully with flagging it with the boss about your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are working at a company that I refer to as a "Meat Grinder."  They tend to pay low to medium wages but suck you in by making vague promises of raises, promotions, and great treatment.  In reality they just want to bring people in and through them at projects.  If the project fails it is not because of the poor management and unreasonable expectations but rather that poor efforts of the team working on the project.  Unpaid OT, often with vague promises of comp time or making it up to them in the future, is a favorite expectation in this type of environment.  The business strategy here is to just keep bringing in relatively low paid devs and use them up and when they are no longer useful and leave.  This type of company will keep developers that are on their 3rd and 4th pip not because they did anything wrong but because they have them afraid they will lose their job at any moment and no one else will hire them.

There is a business strategy that looks at employees as consumables.  This works for McDonald's, Walmart, and many other businesses.  Sadly there is a significant number of executive managers that came from this realm and bring this mindset with them to the white collar world.  This results in their applying the Management vs Workers mentality into other marketplaces.  Add to that the reality that programming is not assembly line type work.  It is part art, part structure, and part math and science.  This leads to a clash where managers think it is just another job and one developer cog can be easily replaced with another developer cog.

If you stick around long enough you can probably get into a management role where you will still feel the pain of unreasonable expectations, but at least then you will be able to inflict pain on some unsuspecting underling that you conned into coming to work for your company.

I have worked for several companies like this over the years.  Most of them can be recognized by the constant churn of their management staff.  If no one on management team was a manager there 5 years ago then there is a good chance the company is a meat grinder.

Comment: What is a pip? Position?

Comment: A Pip is a Performance Improvement Plan... aka a written warning.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder What Chad's saying is that these employers often want people to feel unsafe and unemployable.  Unsafe people don't argue with unreasonable requests.

Comment: @janeS So effectively the workplace equivalent of a bully? Albeit, with the role of money reversed.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder Yes, a bully is a very succinct way of putting it.

Comment: +1 I like the 'developer cog'. This is exactly the mindset many bosses have, not realising that it's nowhere near reality in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have more experience than most of us. That said I've been taken off successful projects to help with projects in the past. (I think this is fairly common among senior developers). It's very possible when your managers look around for an experienced lead they immediately find you. There's something to be said about that. (Ask yourself if there's anyone else that could do it).

> Today, I got called into the boss and was told that the Lead on a project was fired for "not doing a good job" and that the project is now mine. From people I know and respect I know that in senior meetings this project as a bullseye on it. I was honest in saying I was concerned with the health of the project and was told "its actually in good shape" (if you believed that then why did you fire the lead?)

Ask more questions. You need to figure out why this was done. Without that knowledge you can't correct it. At least be 100% sure what the previous lead's direction was and what the major issue was with it. Make it very clear that you have a new direction or changes to remedy the situation. Might sound obvious, but having a record can be nice to reference later like in emails.

> One time I would like to start with a clean sheet and manager my own mistakes.

Might want to raise that point with managers that you'd like to lead a new project when available. Mention that you've been tasked with saving projects in the past and could probably save them a lot of time, even from an architect position, when projects are first started. Remind them that it's not uncommon for managers to pull in senior developers at the start of projects to get multiple viewpoints and directions for solving a project.

Comment: So everyone says you need to have a record, but has anyone actually had an experience where that record was useful? If so, how do you find someone who actually cares to see the record and could change the outcome prior to disaster's striking?

Comment: Actually I have. I started work on a project without 100% control of the direction and sat down with my previous manager (after 2 months of work) and explained that the technology stack we chose was a poor choice. My manager said it was too late to change even though we had just begun. I had emails with him and Skype talks where I explained in detail which parts didn't match our goals and would require a lot of technical debt. When the manager left a few months later I was able to sit down with my boss and show him these records and he agreed on a redesign. (I was lead at that point).

Comment: That's not the same as you're being turfed out for malfeasance and you have records that prove that you did nothing wrong. Everyone says to keep such records, but no one says how to make them useful.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, they are useful generally only if you pursue legal action. Although sometimes, they can be used with HR to get a decision reversed. I have seen 3 people successfully fight a bad review with documentation, but it has to be really unacceptable and unambiguously illegal.

Answer (score 0):

So when the next project arrives, the first thing is a realistic plan what to achieve in what time frame without overtime - take your best estimate, take the next higher unit of time, and multiply by two. Do not accept any change to the time table. Any suggested changes put in writing why a shorter time table is unrealistic and unachievable.

Then you do the job, without any overtime, actually taking off the odd hour here and there to polish your CV, enjoy your time getting paid, make sure that you improve your knowledge of whatever technologies are new, and if there are any complaints point out that you are completely in the time frame that you presented. It might be a good idea to find some new technology that you are interested in and then insist that this technology is absolutely necessary to succeed, giving you an opportunity to improve your marketability.

Seriously, it sounds like you are the kind of person who can easily find a job elsewhere. If the next failed project doesn't get finished, that's not something you should care about.